# Artifactory docker images without manifests

Tags: docker, artifactory

We have a number of broken docker image uploads in Artifactory. It's quite difficult to clean these up, since the package search feature does not find these image tags as packages. In the UI, the only way to remove these without search is 1 tag at a time. I'm curious as to whether anyone else has found a solution for this. Ideally, if there were some AQL or other method to identify and remove any folder in a docker repo that does not contain a manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating AQL Query. AQL has capabilities to search for artifacts based on properties which will help you in achieving clean up the way you want. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language

Comment: AQL is nice, but how do you query something that is missing? - that is the whole issue here

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can trap this with a single AQL, 
but here is an idea that uses 2 AQLs -

1. Prepare a list of all paths that contain a `manifest.json` file
2. Prepare a list of all paths that contain `sha256__*` files 
   (will need to make it unique, because the same path will be 
   listed multiple times, probably)
3. Sort the two lists and compare them to each-other
4. Lines (i.e.: paths) that are showing only in the second list are 
   *paths to broken images that are missing  their manifest file*

Now, after confirming the result-list (from step 4) is correct, 
you can construct from it a set of `DELETE` API-calls (one for each path).